# Why are some axioms preserved in generic extensions?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

It is a known theorem that for a model of $ZF$, $M$, if $M\models AC$ and $G$ is a $P$-generic filter over $M$, for some $P\in M$, then $M[G]\models AC$.

On the other hand, it is long known that other axioms, for example $GCH, CH, V=L, ...$ are not preserved by such extensions.

In a paper of Monro [1] the first paragraph speaks on a question by Dana Scott about why do some axioms get preserved by generic extensions and other not; it also says that there is an [almost obvious] equivalence between preservation in generic extensions, and preservation in Boolean-valued models.

The paper goes on to prove that some restricted versions of the axiom of choice are *not* preserved by generic extensions (and in a recent phone call it was explained to me how to break weak choice principles such $DC_\kappa$ quite easily in relatively simple generic extensions of models of $ZF$).

Lastly the paper says nothing about an answer to the question above, nor it cites any resource for a possible answer. However, the paper is quite old now, and in the past three decades some progress might have occurred.

Is there an answer for Scott's question: *which axioms are preserved by all generic extensions?*

**Edit:** If there is no "simple" and uniform answer to the above question, is there a possible answer to *why is the Axiom of Choice preserved in generic extensions, while restricted versions are not?*

---

**Bibliography:**

1. G. P. Monro, **[On Generic Extensions Without the Axiom of Choice.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2273318)** *The Journal of Symbolic Logic* Vol. 48, No. 1 (Mar., 1983), pp. 39-52

Comment: Just axioms or any sentences?

Comment: It's worth noting that the answer may depend on large cardinal assumptions. For example, by a result of Woodin, the existence of class many measurable Woodin cardinals implies that Sigma-2-1 formulas that are true in one forcing extension are true in all forcing extensions satisfying CH (see the paper of Illias Farah for further discussion).


Comment: I don't think there will be a uniform answer to this question.
Several "axioms" are preserved by generic extensions for absoluteness reasons.  But the reason that AC is preserved depends more on the details of the method of forcing.

Comment: @Francois: Any sentence, I'd assume that some triviality about such sentences is in order; and at the moment I'd be interested mostly in weak choice principles. However if you have any answer that includes non-trivial information on other sentences I'd be happy to hear about that too!

Comment: @Stefan: I'm mostly interested in choice related things and in the construction of forcing extensions. I'll add that to the question too.

Comment: @Haim: As I remarked, I am mostly interested in choice related questions. Mostly since there are not additional consistency requirements there. Answers including large cardinals are interesting too, by the way. (And please turn on your phone, sooner better than later.)

Comment: I was wondering for a moment whether the ordering principle is preserved by generic extensions. I don't know and asked this here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77000

Comment: SVC is preserved by an extension of my earlier answer - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76428/forcing-over-models-without-the-axiom-of-choice/76536#76536

Comment: To add to earlier remarks, I think that too many statements are preserved for somewhat silly reasons (e.g. $\phi^L$ for any $\phi$), or that this is not really the right way to think about the results (e.g. Haim's comment on Woodin's $\Sigma^2_1$ absoluteness). I wonder if there is any way to make formal sense of Stefan's "preserved because of details of the method of forcing"...

Comment: @Francois: This is my question, in a nutshell (although I would be most interested in an answer related to choice principles, which may be slightly more accessible).

Answer (score 7):

In the comments you consider the more general question of
which sentences are necessarily preserved by forcing. One
could cast the question as: what are the most general
relations between set-theoretic *truth* and *forceability*?

This more general setting is the theme of my work with
Benedikt Loewe on [The modal logic of forcing, Trans. AMS,
vol. 360,
2008](http://boolesrings.org/hamkins/themodallogicofforcing/).
The idea here is to investigate the two operators:

- $\varphi$ is *forceable* or *possible*, written
  $\lozenge\varphi$, if $\varphi$ holds in some forcing
  extension.
- $\varphi$ is *necessary*, written $\square\varphi$, if
  $\varphi$ holds in all forcing extensions.

These are modal operators, but they are expressible in the
language of set theory. One can view a set-theoretic
universe in the context of all its forcing extensions as an
enormous Kripke model of possible worlds, with each
accessing its forcing extensions. Your question was, when
can we expect $\varphi\to\square\varphi$?

Our inquiry was what are the most general valid principles
of forcing. For example, one can easily verify the
following validities, under the forcing interpretation:

- (K)  $\ \ \square(\varphi\to \psi)\to (\square\varphi\to
   \square\psi)$
- (Dual)
  $\ \ \neg\lozenge\varphi\leftrightarrow\square\neg\varphi$
- (S) $\ \ \square\varphi\to\varphi$
- (4) $\ \ \square\varphi\to\square\square\varphi$
- (.2) $\ \ \lozenge\square\varphi\to \square\lozenge\varphi$

The last axiom (.2) uses product forcing. The modal theory
obtained from these axioms is known as S4.2. We define that
a modal assertion $\varphi(p_0,\ldots,p_n)$ in the language
of modal logic expresses a *valid principle of forcing* if
$\varphi(\psi_0,\ldots,\psi_n)$ holds with the forcing
interpretation of the modal operators for all set-theoretic
assertions $\psi_0,\ldots,\psi_n$. The main theorem of our
paper is:

**Theorem.** (Hamkins+Loewe) If ZFC is consistent, then
the ZFC-provably valid principles of forcing are exactly
those in the modal theory S4.2.

The proof uses the concept of buttons and switches, where a
set theoretic sentence $\psi$ is a *switch* if both $\psi$
and $\neg\psi$ are necessarily possible, that is, forceable
over any forcing extension, and $\varphi$ is a *button* if
it is possibly necessary, that is, if it can be forced in
such a way that it remains true in any forcing extension.
Thus, switches can be turned on and off, but once you have
pushed a button, you cannot unpush it. The arguments are a
nice blend of easy forcing and modal logic.

Meanwhile, it is consistent that a model can exhibit more
than merely the S4.2 validities. For example, the
*maximality principle* is the scheme asserting:

$$\lozenge\square\varphi\to\square\varphi$$

for all sentences $\varphi$. (See [J. D. Hamkins, A simple
maximality principle, JSL, vol. 68,
2003](http://boolesrings.org/hamkins/maximalityprinciple/),
also independently investigated by Stavi and Vaananen.)
Thus, the maximality principle asserts that any sentence
that could be forced in such a way that it remains true in
all subsequent forcing extensions, is already necessarily
true in this way. Thus, it asserts that all buttons have
been pushed. The maximality principle is equiconsistent
with ZFC, but it is not true that every model of set theory
has a forcing extension with MP. If one allows parameters
into the scheme, the strength rises, and the necessary
maximality principle with real parameters implies
$\text{AD}^{L(\mathbb{R})}$.

The fact that different models of set theory can exhibit
different valid principles of forcing implies that even
when one looks at the general modal form of a set-theoretic
sentence, the question of which sentences are invariant by
forcing will depend on the model of set theory.

Incidently, there are numerous open questions in the modal
logic of forcing. For example, if one restricts to ccc
forcing or to proper forcing or any of several other
natural forcing classes, we don't yet know the exact modal
theory of validites. What are the ZFC-provably valid
principles of ccc forcing?

Comment: Joel, many thanks for the answer. It seems that the axiom of choice is used here aplenty. How much of this holds without it?

Comment: I guess it is still correct to say that the ZF-provably valid principles of forcing are still S4.2, since these are valid also for forcing over ZF models, and for the upper bound, one can still use the ZFC model, since it suffices to have a single ZF model whose validities are contained in S4.2. But perhaps one might attack the question about intermediate logics between S4.2 and S5 by means of a ZF model in which AC fails badly. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

**Forward:** This answer does not address the main question "which statements are preserved for every generic extension." Which I suspect has no simple answer.

**Lets start** by defining what this answer is meant to address: Preservation results fall into two types (modulo fine details):

1. Large structural preservation. 
   An example of this kind is Shoenfield's classic result concerning the absoluteness of $\Sigma^1_2$ statements. These generally take the form: For some statement(s) $\varphi$ and "canonical" inner model $M$, we can show that $ZFC \vdash $"$\varphi $ is absolute for $M,V$ ". This is rapidly transformed into a forcing absoluteness result by cleverly setting up the notion of "canonical" so as to guarantee: if $V \subset N$ are models of $ZFC$ and $V\vDash M$ is "canonical", then $N \vDash M$ is "canonical." (In the case of Shoenfield's result this last bit is trivial since $V\subset N \implies L^V = L^N$.)
2. Small combinatorial preservation. 
   These results are numerous and deal with individual statements assumed to hold in the ground model and then using this assumption produce that the statement is true in the extension (using either the definability of forcing or constructing explicit names of objects in the extension, or a combination of both.) Moreover, results of this form can be considered as the reason a certain statement holds in an extension. These types of proofs can be understood as being essentially internal to $V$.

The contents of this answer will attempt to illustrate two examples of the second method and explain why $AC$ is preserved when passing to any generic extension.

**Now for a horrible and vague answer to a strange question:** What does using a partial order $\mathbb{P}$ to force over a model $V$ actually do? It lets people with imaginations strictly confined to $V$ imagine/build an exterior universe $V[G]$ (whose properties are bound to $\mathbb{P}$, the forcing relation $\Vdash_{\mathbb{P}}$, and $V$.)

From this perspective the original question can be recast as: How does one prove certain statements are  preserved by a particular $\mathbb{P}$? The answer: it depends, but in general there are two methods which appear most. From here we will consider a couple examples.

**Consider the case of $AC$**: Now, $AC$ is equivalent to the statement $ \forall X\ \exists \alpha \in ON\,\  f\subset X \times \alpha\ (\ f$ is injective$)$ and we want to show that this statement is preserved between forcing extensions.

**First Method:** (Brute force combinatorics) (paraphrasing what is found in Kunens' text)

We must show $\forall p\in \mathbb{P}\ \exists q \le p\ [q \Vdash \forall \dot{X}\ \exists\check{\alpha}\in ON,\ \dot{f} \subset \dot{X} \times \check{\alpha}\ (\dot{f} $ is an injection with domain $\dot{X})]$. Using the standard facts about the forcing relation $\Vdash$, this becomes: for every $\dot{X} \in V^{\mathbb{P}}$ and $p \in \mathbb{P}$, there exists some $q \le p$, $\alpha \in ON$, and $\dot{f}\in V^{\mathbb{P}}$ such that $q \Vdash [\ \dot{f} $ is an injection with domain $\dot{X}\ ].$

In order to show this assertion, we are going to explicitly build the name $\dot{f}$, and produce the condition $q$ which forces "$\dot{f} $ *is an injection with domain* $\dot{X}$" only using statements $ZF+AC$ can prove.

To this end, note that since we are assuming $AC$, we may assume $\dot{X} = \bigcup_{\gamma\in\mu}\{ \langle \sigma_\gamma, q \rangle: q \in A_\gamma \}$, where each $\sigma_\gamma$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name, $\mu$ is some cardinal, and $A_\gamma$ is an anti-chain such that $\forall q \le p$: we have $q \Vdash [\sigma_\gamma \in \dot{X}]$, if and only if $\{ s \in A_\gamma: s \not\perp q \}$ is maximal below $q$.

Let $\dot{g}= \bigcup_{\alpha\in\mu} \{ \langle \rho_\alpha(q), q \rangle: q \in A_\alpha \}$ where $\rho_\alpha(q) = \{\langle \sigma_\alpha, q \rangle, \langle \{\langle \sigma_\alpha, q \rangle, \langle \check{\alpha}, q \rangle, \}, q \rangle \}$. Then, taking $q=p$, $\alpha = \mu$ and $\dot{f} = \dot{g}$ establishes the result.

**Second Method:** (Sage like and Model Theoretic)

The statement "$f$ *is an injection*" is $\Delta_0$. Moreover, if $f$ is an injection, then  $ZF(?C)$ proves that the same holds for all of its subsets. Noting that for every $\dot{X} \in V^{\mathbb{P}}$ there exists some $Y \in V$ such that $ 1 \Vdash \exists \dot{g} \subset \dot{X} \times \check{Y}\ (\dot{g} $ is an injection $)$ (namely $Y = \{\langle \sigma, q \rangle^\check{\ }: \langle \sigma, q \rangle \in \dot{X} \}$) and by $AC$ there exists some injection $f : Y \to \mu$ (some cardinal $\mu$), the result follows.

**Conclusion for $AC$:** The reason $AC$ is preserved when passing to a generic extension is essentially because it is equivalent to a "well-positioned" statement. Where "well-positioned" in this case means: it asserts the existence of an object with a $\Delta_0$ property and this $\Delta_0$ property is maintained by each of its subsets, all of which can be turned into a witness for some particular instance of $AC$. In this way, the truth or falsity of $AC$ in the extension does not depend on $\mathbb{P}$ and depends only on whether or not it held in $V$.

To contrast this with other weak forms of $AC$: consider $DC_\omega$. In order for $DC_\omega$ to be preserved we must avoid something. In particular we must avoid adding some $R \subset X \times X$ which is an entire binary relation and witnesses the failure of $DC_\omega$ (i.e. there is no $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ so that $\langle x_n, x_{n+1} \rangle \in R$) and we have no reason to expect this is the case without knowing something about $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: The ordering principle can be written as $\forall X\exists R\subseteq X\times X: R\text{ is a total order on } X$, where as being a relation is $\Delta_0$, and being a total order is also $\Delta_0$ (all quantifiers are bounded). How is the ordering principle different than the axiom of choice in that matter? As I answered Stefan Geschke's question - the ordering principle **is not preserved** under forcing.

Comment: @Asaf every subset of $R$ need not be a total order. The trick that makes the AC result hold is that it is provably the case that every subset of $f$ must also be an injection.

Comment: This is the same reason it is possible to break $DC_\omega$

Comment: Michael, restricting a linear order to yields a linear order on a smaller domain; I also did not discuss any subset of $R$. I just say that there exists a subset of $X\times X$ which is a total order. However I look at this axiom again and $\exists R\subseteq X\times X$ is not $\Delta_0$ and the quantification is not bounded either since the power set is not a $\Delta_0$ property.

Comment: I'm sorry for any confusion, I thought what you were asking was relating to what I called "well-positioned." Think about it like this, because we can fix $\alpha$ in my $AC$ example, we have limited the ability of $\mathbb{P}$ to diagonalize and produce a counter-example. Where as for $DC$ or the general existence of a total-ordering, you can generically avoid witnesses to "$\dot{X}\times\dot{X}$ has a subset of type ____"

Comment: The distinguishing characteristic here is that $AC$ has an absolute class of canonical objects $ON$ to which you can provably reduce every well-ordering.

Comment: Jech *The Axiom of Choice*, Theorem 8.9 p.127, $\forall\lambda(AC_\lambda)$ does not even imply $W_{\aleph_1}$.

Comment: Correction of my previous comment: Also, it worth noting that the restriction of the well ordering principle is almost completely independent of the restriction of the existence of choice functions. We only have for singular cardinals $\lambda$ that $\forall\kappa<\lambda(W_\kappa\land AC_{\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)}$ imply together $W_\lambda$. (where Wκ is to say that κ is comparable with every cardinal). This is theorem 8.1 in the above citation. Just to show the further lack of relation between $AC_\kappa$ and $W_\lambda$.

Comment: I would doubt that, as these things has been checked thoroughly throughout the years. I would suspect, however, that you think that there is any relation between choice function on *well orderable families* and comparability with cardinals.

Comment: retracted, after reading the proof of the first embedding theorem more carefully it does.

Comment: I suspect you are looking for some deeper connection between the preservation of AC and its weaker forms, which is compatible with their relationships (this is not the case for reasons fundamental to forcing.) If this is the case I will remove my answer, since it would not present anything relevant.

Comment: Well, I am not looking for the connection between compatibility of weak choice forms and their preservation. I am rather looking for the reason that weak choice principles can be violated by forcing, while the axiom of choice cannot be violated by forcing. (For example, it is simple to have a model of $DC_\kappa$ (and therefore $AC_\kappa$ and $W_\kappa$) and then violate $W_{\aleph_0}$ by a simple forcing.)

Comment: Its because forcing allows you to disconnect the existence of subsets of $\dot{X}\times\dot{X}$ from $\dot{X}$ in an essential way that is terribly difficult to "trap." Because we have AC in the ground model, we are able to reduce the problem to a new subset of some ground model $Y$, from which a well-ordering of $Y$ transfers to a well-ordering of its new subset $\dot{X}$ using the equivalent form of choice stated in my answer. 

Comment: As evidence for my claim, suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is a CCC po, such that $\mathbb{P}^2$ is CCC, and $\mathbb{P}^3$ is not CCC. Then, $1 \Vdash_{\mathbb{P}} \check{\mathbb{P}} \times \check{\mathbb{P}}$ is not CCC. The only thing that changed here is that there is a new uncountable subset of $\mathbb{P}^2$ forming an anti-chain.

Comment: Michael, your mystical proof is a bit too mystical for me.  You wrote "for every $\dot{X} \in V^{\mathbb{P}}$ there exists some $Y \in V$ such that $\forall p\in\mathbb{P}\ ( p \Vdash \dot{X} \subset \check{Y})$."  This would mean that every set in the forcing extension is a subset of a set from the ground model, which isn't true --- consider for example the singleton of the generic filter.  I think you need to work with a ground model set $Y$ that contains enough *names* for elements of $X$ so that the forcing extension sees a surjection from $\check{Y}$ onto $X$.

Comment: @Andreas Blass, thank you for pointing that out, I think I've fixed it. Also changed mystic to sage like.

Comment: And ev'ryone will say / 
As you walk your mystic way, /
"If this young man expresses himself /
In terms too deep for me, / 
Why, what a very singularly deep young man /
This deep young man must be!"


Comment: Very ironic....