# Do choice principles in all generic extensions imply AC in $V$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, axiom-of-choice

It's well-known that not all choice principles are preserved under forcing, e.g. in this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/77002/109573 Asaf shows the ordering principle can hold in $V$ and fail in a generic extension. Indeed, the standard proof for preservation of AC is based on the fact that well-orderability is preserved under surjection, a fact that doesn't seem to have any nice generalization for weaker choice principles at all. So I wonder if we can get any results in the opposite direction.

> Are there any known results of the form "If all generic extensions satisfy [some weak choice principle] then [some stronger choice principle] holds in $V$"?

I take choice principles to include e.g. AC, DC, AC$_{\omega}$, the selection principle, "all infinite sets are Dedekind-infinite," and "(strongly) amorphous sets don't exist." Two conjectures I want to focus on are:

> Plausible conjecture: AC$_{\omega}$ in all generic extensions implies AC in $V$ (the idea here is that if there's a set in $V$ without a choice function, maybe there's a way to collapse its cardinality to $\omega$ without adding a choice function),

and

> Ridiculous conjecture: If every generic extension has no strongly amorphous sets, then AC holds in $V$ (I can't believe this is true, but I also have no idea what property $V$ can have to prevent forcing amorphous sets).

Comment: I suppose it should be all non-trivial extensions, since if trivial forcing is included the answer is always yes. In any case, I like the question.

Comment: I am including trivial forcing. I don't see how that gives a positive answer. I'm only assuming the generic extensions (including $V$) satisfy weak choice principles.

Comment: This somehow reminds me of Solovay's theorem stating that for every forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$, if a set $a$ exists in every generic extension by $\mathbb{P}$ it must already exist in the ground model.

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse the cardinality of a set $X$ to $\omega$ without adding a choice function"?  If you add a bijection between $X$ and $\omega$, you certainly add a choice function from $P(X)\setminus \{0\}$ to $X$,

Comment: I assume that "generic extension" means "set-generic".

Comment: I mean set-generic but an answer for class-generic would be nice as well.

Comment: $X$ is the family of sets I want a choice function on, not $P(X).$

Comment: This is a tough question. Looking back [after seven years](https://mathoverflow.net/q/76995/7206), I can now say that I feel that the main reason that AC is preserved under generic extensions is that AC is stating that surjections admits inverses. But in reality this amounts to injections rather than inverses. So the Partition Principle should be enough for that. The problem, however, is that the relation between full choice and the Partition Principle is one of the toughest nuts to crack in choiceless set theory. [...]

Comment: While your questions and conjectures are very interesting, I feel that somehow people are often too focused on these families of choice principles, and that's somehow limiting. PP and KWP (Kinna–Wagner Principles) seem to be much more pertinent to the generic multiverse. While they are not as famous, PP does imply DC (for example), so if it is indeed the case that PP is preserved in generic extensions, then countable choice would be preserved too and it would serve as a counterexample. Or a proof that PP implies full choice. In either case, it's a hard problem to tackle. [...]

Comment: Unless, of course, the obvious solution works. But for that one has to sit down and think about it. And it's mighty late here for doing just that now.

Comment: I am pleased to see such a question, which can be expressed explicitly in modal terms as $\Box\text{AC}^-\to\text{AC}^+$, using the forcing modality, where $\text{AC}^-$ is the weak choice principle and $\text{AC}^+$ is the stronger one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A silly question: is DC preserved by set forcing? Monro's paper shows that the answer is negative for limited versions of DC, but I couldn't find an answer for DC itself. Also, do you know of a single example of a choice principle other than AC itself which is preserved by set forcing? (This is necessarily subjective, I know, but I'm curious; for what it's worth, I don't consider SVC, "the Dedekind-finite cardinalities are bounded," etc. to be choice principles.)

Comment: @Noah: Uh, no? If you look closely at Monro's paper he doesn't violate bounded version of DC, but rather strong versions of DC. And to your question, I guess my answer would be no. I would add, though, that proper forcing cannot violate DC. So that's something.

Comment: @Noah: By the way, SVC is "generic AC", which is arguably very much a choice principle. The first KWPs are choice and the selection principle, both considered as choice principles through and through.

Comment: Here is one solution:  if every forcing extension has a definable global well-order, then anything follows.  (Because adding a Cohen real destroys definable global AC, and so the hypothesis is false.)

Comment: @Joel: You can modify that to "definable from a parameter"...

Comment: @AsafKaragila No you can't, because being HOD of a parameter is forcing invariant. I once made a blog post about this: http://jdh.hamkins.org/being-hod-of-a-set-is-invariant-throughout-the-generic-multiverse/

Comment: @Joel: Yes, I know that, it wasn't a question. :)

Comment: My point was that your comment was incorrect, since the solution doesn't work when you allow parameters, precisely because you can't destroy that form of choice by forcing.

Comment: @Joel: Admittedly, at this point I am a bit lost as to where the conversation had gone to. So there is a good chance of misunderstanding on my side.

Comment: Here is a solution of the dual form:  weak choice statement implies strong choice statement holds in some forcing extension.  Namely, if ZFC and V=HOD(b), then there is a forcing extension with V=HOD.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a partial answer.

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $\mathcal X=\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint sets which does not admit a choice function, and let $\Bbb P$ be a forcing which is well-orderable. Then $\Bbb P$ cannot force a choice function from $\cal X$.

*Proof.* Suppose that $\dot f$ is a name such that $p\Vdash\dot f\text{ is a choice function from }\check{\mathcal X}$. Enumerate $\Bbb P$, and let $F(i)=x$ if and only if the least condition $q\leq p$ in the enumeration, such that $q$ decides the value of $\dot f(\check i)$, forced $\dot f(\check i)=\check x$. $\quad\square$

> **Corollary.** Suppose that $\sf AC_\kappa$ fails, then there is a generic extension where $\sf AC_\omega$ fails.

*Proof.* Note that $\kappa^{<\omega}$, or $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\kappa)$ is a well-orderable forcing. $\quad\square$

> **Corollary.** If $\sf AC_\omega$ holds in every generic extension then $\sf AC_{\rm WO}$, and therefore $\sf DC$ hold in every generic extension.

*Proof.* Otherwise, collapse a suitably large $\kappa$ to be countable. Additionally, note that a generic extension of a generic extension is itself a generic extension. $\quad\square$

---

This means that it is enough to verify that if $\mathsf{AC}_{\rm WO}$ holds, i.e. $\forall\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord},\sf AC_{\aleph_\alpha}$, then there is a generic extension where it fails. This principle is weaker than $\sf AC$, but it does imply $\sf DC$ (not $\sf DC_{\aleph_1}$, though).

Unfortunately, the above method hits a roadblock since $X^{<\omega}$ is not well-orderable for an arbitrary set, and indeed forcing with $X^{<\omega}$ can easily add choice functions to the universe, and in fact on occasion also the axiom of choice in its full glory.

Comment: Very nice! I like it very much.

Comment: To be fair, this is something I have noticed a few years ago. I recall telling Uri Abraham this theorem on a car trip back from Jerusalem to Beersheba when I was a student. I might have even written this in some answer on MO before, because I have a strong feeling of deja vu about it at the moment.

Comment: (I am also pretty sure that I am not the first person to have noticed that. If I were a gambling man, I would have bet that Hugh had known this since the 1980s at least. Probably the same can be said about a few other logicians too.)

Comment: I guess you also get DC, since AC_WO implies DC. So if countable choice holds in all forcing extensios, then DC, which is an attractive way to say it.

Comment: Oh, that's a good observation. I will edit it in once I'm on the train.

Comment: And here I was debating whether to include AC$_{WO}$ in my list of choice principles at the beginning. Good to see this axiom put to use.

Comment: @Elliot: Indeed. Note that $\sf AC_{\rm WO}$ is equivalent to $\aleph(X) = \aleph^*(X)$ for all $X$. Or, every surjection onto a well ordered set splits. This makes combinatorial arguments harder, because you need to use non well ordered sets all over the place, and those can be unruly, and more importantly their properties are very undecidable. So this makes these sort of proofs very hard.

Answer (score 5):

Working on a related topic for a new paper with Jonathan Schilhan I've stumbled into a disproof of your ridiculous conjecture.

> **Definition.** The class $W$ is the closure of $\{\{a\}\mid a\in V\}$ under well-ordered unions. Sets in $W$ are called "almost well-orderable sets".

The axiom $V=W$ is consistent with $\lnot\sf AC$, for example in Gitik's model, and in a large cardinals-free model, Blass' model where all ultrafilters are principal.

**Theorem.** If $V=W$, then there are no amorphous sets.

*Proof.* We define a rank function based on how many steps it requires to generate a set using well-ordered unions of singletons, call this the $W$-rank of a set. If $A$ is amorphous of minimal rank, then it is a well-ordered union of proper subsets. Since $A$ is minimally ranked, those must be finite sets, as an infinite subset of an amorphous set is amorphous. So the union must be infinite, and therefore $A$ can be mapped onto $\omega$, at the very least, which is impossible. $\square$

**Theorem.** If $V=W$ and $G$ is $V$-generic, then $V[G]=W^{V[G]}$.

*Proof.* Note that there is a surjection from $V$ onto $V[G]$, definable in $V[G]$. Or, formally speaking, for every set in $V[G]$ there is a set in $V$ which maps onto it. Moreover, the closure of $\{\{a\}\mid a\in V[G]\}$ under well-ordered unions, in $V[G]$, contains $V$.

So if we show that this closure is itself closed under surjective images, we are done. This too is done by induction on the $W$-rank. If $x=\bigcup_{\alpha<\delta}x_\alpha$ and $f\colon x\to y$ is a surjection, then by the induction hypothesis $f``x_\alpha=y_\alpha$ is in the closure, and of course $y=\bigcup_{\alpha<\delta}y_\alpha$. $\square$

Finally, the wanted corollary.

**Corollary.** If $V=W$, then no generic extension of $V$ contains amorphous sets.

---

On the other hand, over the Cohen model, where $W$ is the class of well-orderable sets, there is a forcing adding an amorphous set (as was shown by Monro). So while the above shows that the ridiculous conjecture is false, it is not entirely clear how ridiculous it was to begin with. Namely, can we refine it to something "more or less" in the spirit of $V\neq W$?

Comment: "Almost well-orderable" is a nice notion! The Bernstein set result I told you about can be phrased as "if $\mathbb{R}$ is almost well-orderable, then there is a Bernstein set."

Comment: It is a nice notion. Normally you just start with the class of well-orderable sets as the "ground level", but I originally adapted this from work related to the Gitik model, so I started with countable sets and countable unions. And I got too lazy to rewrite everything from scratch with better details.

Comment: Re the last paragraph: this sounds like an approach to resolving the plausible conjecture. If $V \neq W$ implies that countable choice fails in some extension, that combined with your other answer would prove the conjecture.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer: Well, the plausible one anyway. Keep an eye out in the next week or so, the first draft is complete, and I expect that by the end of next week we'll finish proofing it and put it online.