# Forcing the nonexistence of a certain set

Tags: set-theory, forcing, axiom-of-choice, lo.logic, ct.category-theory

I have a certain set-theoretic axiom ([WISC](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/WISC)) which follows from Choice (this is a nuking a fly BTW), but which I suspect is independent of ZF. To show this I need to show that a certain set does not exist. I have no experience with forcing, but I'm willing to learn. I have a plan of attack, but would like to know if it is what I should be doing, or whether some other approach is needed.

Here are the details, and apologies for the vagueness of the questions.

> WISC - for every set $S$, there is a set $C_S\subset \{ p:A\to S |\ p\ \mbox{is onto}\}$ such that 
>   $$ \forall\ \mbox{surjections }f:B\to S\ \exists (p:A\to S)\in C_S,\ s:A\to B \mbox{ such that } f\circ s = p
> $$

Clearly, to show this is independent of ZF (or other set-theoretic foundations), we just need a set $S$ such that $C_S$ doesn't exist. We might as well try as a first attempt $S = \mathbb{N}$. If we had a countable model of ZF, if we could force that $C_\mathbb{N}$ was bounded below in size by some uncountable set, and still have a countable model, then I believe we would be done.

> Question 1: Is this approach likely to work, or is it too naive?

Notice that one implication of $\lnot$WISC is that there are a proper class of non-split surjections, but this is not sufficient to conclude $\lnot$WISC. Or in the above approach, we would have an uncountable collection of non-split surjections.

Failing the approach above, and in the absence of other options for $\mathbb{N}$, one could step it up a notch and try $C=\mathbb{R}$, but would obviously need a different strategy. Given that I'm familiar in principle with forcing to the level covered in MacLane-Moerdijk (a topos theoretic approach, but not very in-depth),

> Question 2: What are good references to get a feel for what one can force along these lines (violations of Choice)?

I'm thinking Blass' paper on SVC might be a good start, but I may need to read something else before that.

I'm trying to show that a particular class is not a set, so perhaps I need to work with NBG + $\lnot$C, and use conservativity over ZF, but given this question: [Forcing over models without the axiom of choice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76428/forcing-over-models-without-the-axiom-of-choice), one might suppose that forcing over foundations without Choice other than ZF is even rarer.

The alternative is to consider a quantitative version of WISC, where the set $C_S$ must have cardinality less than a given (regular) cardinal $\kappa$. In the case that $\kappa$ is inaccessible, we can take a Grothendieck universe and so recover the original version of WISC. The presentation axiom/COSHEP is the case when this $\kappa = 2$. Conversely, to show independence, we could just force that $|C_S| \ge \kappa$ for inaccessible $\kappa$, and so show that there is no small set $C_S$ (relative to the universe given by $\kappa$).

> Question 3: is this a better way to go about it?

Comment: The problem with forcing is that it preserves AC, so you can't force ¬WISC starting with a model of AC. You can make AC fail by passing to a symmetric submodel, but then the technologically simpler permutation models would be the first thing to try. Unfortunately most of these will fail too since set-forcing extensions and set-based permutation models will preserve SVC. So one needs use a symmetric submodel of a class-forcing extension in order to arrive at a model of ¬WISC. There are very few of those around...

Comment: @François Well, I mean to start from ZF + $\lnot$C, but I infer from your comment that something in my question means I am secretly accepting Choice somewhere. Is it in the countable model?

Comment: By the way, from the categorical point of view, it is harder distinguish between pure forcing extensions, symmetric models, and in-between options. See Blass and Scedrov, *Freyd's models for the independence of the axiom of choice* (Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 79, 1989).

Comment: @Francois: Do permutation models over a class of atoms act like symmetric submodels of class-forcing extensions?

Comment: @David: No, it's that it's customary to start with a model of AC (e.g. L) and then take a symmetric model to do something different. There are very few handy models of ¬AC to start with (and all those I can think of satisfy SVC). Theoretically, you could start with a model where AC fails very badly, but then there is a good chance WISC already fails there without doing anything.

Comment: @François "Theoretically, you could start with a model where AC fails very badly" that would be nice. Where can I get one? :) Alternatively, I would be completely happy finding a (Grothendieck) topos where WISC failed (suitably interpreted in the internal language, or take well-pointed for simplicity). 

Comment: @David: I believe I have seen such beasts in the past, but since I've never had any real use for them I can't think of any useful reference right now. (I am hoping that Andreas will drop by shortly with the appropriate model in hand...)

Comment: @François ok, I wait and see.

Comment: @David, are you allowing $A$ to range over every set? I don't understand, because if you are allowing $A$ to range over arbitrary sets then $C_S$ is always a class. Unless perhaps you meant injection?

Comment: @David, maybe you meant every pair of sets A,S?

Comment: @Michael - no, just bad notation on my behalf. I'll fix it.

Comment: @David, you might want to note that $C_S$ can always be taken to be just the identity, which means that as stated, $WISC$ is always true.

Comment: @David, for what its worth, in order for forcing or large cardinals to change a certain statement $\varphi$, $\varphi$ needs to be something which doesn't have definable witnesses.

Comment:  @Michael, "you might want to note that CS can always be taken to be just the identity, - no, that is just the result that AC implies WISC. As far as your other statement goes, I don't know what you mean, as I don't know enough forcing/set theory (see my first para).

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. Was reading much too fast, $f\circ s = p$ and not $f = s\circ p$. 

Comment: @David: It turns out I did once need such a monster! See the paper by Gitik in this MO answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33028/can-iterating-countable-unions-give-every-set-zf/33032#33032 This is *not* an easy model, but there is a chance WISC fails in it.

Comment: @François - so SVC fails in Gitik's model? Or just AC fails 'badly'? Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 2):

This is just to answer the reference request part of the question, I'm making this community wiki so that you can add your favorite references.

- The best place to learn about permutation models and symmetric models is Jech's *The Axiom of Choice*. It's not recent, but all the classic models are there and it's packed with tons of useful information.
- For the bridge between category-theoretic and set-theoretic methods, the main resource should be Blass and Scedrov *Freyd's models for the independence of the axiom of choice* (Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 79, 1989).

Answer (score 1):

Jech's book has a current reprint, so it can be bought.

Comment: Best 12 USD I spent in the passing year! (shipping not included, sadly...)